# What is the minimum size of an address register for a computer with 5TB of memory?

Tags: hardware, cpu-registers

There is this question that I'm having a bit a difficulty to answer

Here it is:

An n-bit register can hold 2^n distinct bit patterns.  As such,
it can only be used to address a memory whose number of addressable units
(typically, bytes) is less than or equal to 2^n.  In this question, register
sizes need not be a power of two.  K = 2^10

a) What is the minimum size of an address register for a computer
with 5 TB of memory?

b) What is the minimum size of an address register for a computer
with 7 TBs of memory?

c) What is the minimum size of an address register for a computer
with 2.5 PBs of memory?

From the conversion, I know that:

1KB = $2^{10}$ bytes

1MB = $2^{20}$ bytes

1GB = $2^{30}$ bytes

1TB = $2^{40}$ bytes

If I convert 5TB into bytes we get 5,497,558,138,880 bytes

What would be the next step though? I know that 1 byte = 8 bits

Comment: "1 byte = 8 bits" is irrelevant. The memory sizes are in gigabytes/petabytes, not bits, so there's no need to convert between bits and bytes anywhere along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would proceed:

1 TB = 2^40 bytes

Calculate the number of bytes in 5 TB = 5,497,558,138,880 bytes (assume this number is n);

The logarithmic function log(Base2)(n) = the minimum size of an address register and in this case it would be 42.321928095 bits which I would round up to 43 bits.

Same logic for the other questions.

Comment: I used cross multiplication 1TB = 2^40 and 5TB  = 2^n and solved for n. What I did is (log(5 x 2^40))/(log(2)) and got the exact same answer.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you divide by 8.

5,497,558,138,880/8 = 687194767360

Using logarithms, 2^n = 687194767360 therefore log2(687194767360) = n

Therefore n = 39.321928095

The same steps can be used to achieve part b and c

Comment: Wouldn't we have to multiply by 8? Since 1 byte = 8 bits?